# Express matrix inverse with αA+βI

Tags: matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations

Hi I have a characteristic polynomial of matrix A: $$p(x)=x^2+x+1$$

and I have to express inverse of a matrix A with  $$A^{-1}=αA+βI$$ where α and β are real numbers. I don't know where to go from here.

I know that this is true:
$$AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$$

Comment: Hint: every matrix satisfies its own characteristic polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: So you know that $p(A)=A^2+A+I=0$. Therefore
$$I=-A-A^2=A(-I-A),$$ so...

Comment: $A^2+A+1=0$ so $A^{-1}=-1-A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A) = 0$$ 
$$A^2 + A + I = 0$$
$$A(A+I) = -I$$
$$A(-A-I) = I$$
so $A^{-1} = -A-I$.

Comment: I find answers without words deeply antipedagogical...

Answer (score 1):

From the Cayley-Hamilton you get that $p(A)=0$; in other words, $A^2+A+\operatorname{Id}=0$. So$$A+\operatorname{Id}+A^{-1}=A^{-1}(A^2+A+\operatorname{Id})=0.$$ In other words, $A^{-1}=-A-\operatorname{Id}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without Cayley Hamilton: The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_1}$ where $\lambda_2=-\lambda_1-1$ and $\lambda_1=-\lambda_2-1$ and there exists an invertible matrix $T$ such that

$TAT^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\0&\lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$. Since $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|=1$ one has

$TA^{-1}T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_2 & 0\\0&\lambda_1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\lambda_1-1 & 0\\0&-\lambda_2-1\end{pmatrix}=-TAT^{-1}-I$.

Multiplying by $T^{-1}$ from the left and by $T$ from the right yields the result.